# Meanings of function keys on the keyboard and of special icons on the lid on a laptop

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad

My laptop is Lenovo T400. I was wondering

1. what the meanings of the function
   keys with those blue icons on the
   keyboard are?
2. what the meanings of the flashing
   icons on the bottom of the lid are?
   I can only understand the one for
   showing if having wireless
   connection.

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the Make and specific model of notebook you have, you will get a more informed answer this way.

Comment: @Moab: Sorry, I only know my laptop is Lenovo T400.

Comment: @Moab - ThinkPads aren't as bad about variations between submodels as some vendors. "T400" is descriptive enough for the question at hand.  (If the question was, say, "What resolution screen do I have?" then full type-model number would be needed.)

Comment: @Shinrai: what is full type-model number like?

Comment: @Tim - Look on the label with the serial number.  You should have 'MT' 'Machine Type' 'Type' or something to that effect.  A T400 might be, say, "2767-WQN".  These code for specific hardware configuration combinations.

Comment: T400 user guide here....http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-70193

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a good diagram on the setup flyer that came with the machine, which you can also find [here](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?lndocid=MIGR-70084).  The LEDs don't seem to be there but I think they're inside Access Help (which in Windows 7 integrates itself into the Help and Support heading on the Start Menu).

EDIT: IIRC, the first set of LEDS is for WLAN/WAN/Bluetooth radios, second set is NumLock/CapsLock, and the last batch is HDD access/sleep/power/etc etc.

Comment: @Shinrai: Thanks! Among the LEDs, What does "Z" in a circle mean, and how about the waning moon?

Comment: The moon is the sleep icon (same as you should see on F4).  I honestly forget what the Z icon is for...I'll actually have a W510 in house tomorrow and I'll check and get back to you, haha!  EDIT: Oh, wait, that might just be the 'machine is powered on' indicator.

Comment: @Shinrai: What does the plug-in LED mean?

Comment: @Tim - Quite literally, that the machine is plugged in.

Comment: @Shinrai: Do Z and plug-in mean the same?

Comment: @Tim - No.  One means the machine is plugged in, one means the machine is powered on.  The two obviously CAN but don't necessarily overlap.

Comment: @Shinrai: in what cases, one but not the other?

Comment: @Tim - Sorry, I thought this was patently obvious.  If the machine is turned on, the Z light will be enabled.  If the machine is plugged in, the plug light will be enabled.  Therefore, if the machine is plugged in and off, only the plug light will be on.  If you then turn it on, the Z light should come on.  If you then unplug it and run on battery, the plug light will go off.  If you then turn it off, the Z light will go off.  I don't know how to be any clearer, sorry. ;)

Comment: @Shinrai: Thanks! I am very ignorant most of the time.